# Lockfile in multi-user Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-users

A friend of mine posted this on facebook:

**Original post in Norwegian**

> hvis du åpner Excel med en bruker og deretter åpner samme filen med
>   en annen bruker så åpnes ikke filen på nytt fordi Excel skjønner at
>   filen allerede er åpen.. men det er jo ikke på min bruker? er det kun
>   mulig fordi jeg er en "administrator" og shell prosessen finner det ut
>   eller?

**Translation**

> If you open Excel with a user and then open the same file with another
>   user, the file will not reopen because Excel understands that the file
>   is already open .. but it is not the same user? Is it only possible
>   because I'm an "administrator" and the shell process finds it out or?

How is this possible?

The lockfile ~$[filename] and $appdata$ recovery files are untouched.

Only one of the users is in an admin group.

Steps to reproduce;

1. Run CMD as different user.
2. Start Excel with a filename as a parameter from the CMD process.

   - The Excel process should now be running as "the other user".
3. Open the same file from an explorer process running as "your user".

Another Excel process running as your user will not be started because the file is already open in the other user's Excel process.

Comment: Can you clarify? is Excel shared or for multiuser or not?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your network. 
I am an administrator for our IT system and other users have no problems opening "read only" versions of any excel file I already have open.

Comment: The file are opened in the same instance locally, not shared or multiuser. The question is: how could two different user open the same file in one instance of excel?